# DataTables (API)- clear and readd data to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables and the below works great to populate and render the table

```
loadTableDS = function (data) {

    var len = data.d.length;

    if (len > 0) {
        var r = new Array(), j = -1;

        for (var key = 0, size = len; key < size; key++) {
            r[++j] = '<tr><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].CRMFieldOperativeGuid.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].Eastings.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ActualDistance.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ActualTravelTimeMinutes.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].Northings.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].PostcodeNS.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].RES_TYPE_ID.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].RS_ID.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ResourceCode.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ResourceAvailableStart.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ResourceAvailableEnd.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].FullName.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].Postcode.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].EstimatedDistance.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = getDateTime(data.d[key].ResourceAvailableStart);
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = getDateTime(data.d[key].ResourceAvailableEnd);
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].EstimatedInstructionTimeMinutes.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].EstimatedTravelTimeMinutes.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td><td>';
            r[++j] = data.d[key].ResourceType.toString();
            r[++j] = '</td></tr>';

        }

        $('#tblDayShiftEngineers tbody').html(r.join(''));

        var dsengineers = $('#tblDayShiftEngineers').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "info": false,
            "lengthChange": true,
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
                "sRowSelect": "single",
                "aButtons": ""
            }
        });

        // hide the first 11 columns 
        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            dsengineers.column(i).visible(false);
        }

    }
}
```

The table is populated and the first 11 rows are hidden. The **data** variable is populated from an ajax call.

Now I need to be able to refresh the table, that is recall the function, clear all the existing rows and repopulate with the new **data** variable.

I moved the initialising of the table to the beginning of the function:

```
loadTableDS = function (data) {


    var dsengineers = $('#tblDayShiftEngineers').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "info": false,
        "lengthChange": true,
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sRowSelect": "single",
            "aButtons": ""
        }
    });

    // hide the first 11 columns 
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        dsengineers.column(i).visible(false);
    }

    var len = data.d.length;

    if (len > 0) {
```

but that doesn't work because the 11 data columns are still there (i also tried moving the hiding code to after the table is populated - makes no difference).

I've tried clear().draw(); and no joy.

Can someone please give me a pointer, even psuedo code on where I'm going wrong before I throw my PC out of the window! :)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of DataTables you're using, but I use:

```
if($tableloaded == false){
    loadTable();
} else {
    $('#jobTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    loadTable();
}
```

this works perfectly for me.

Also, this is from DataTables current API:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#tableDestroy').on( 'click', function () {
   table.destroy();
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I ended up leaving the function as was and then in the resetting call, using your fnDestroy() function and $("#tblDayShiftEngineers tbody > tr").remove(); to remove the data - works perfectly now :) #happygirlie